# Does services like Trove, Ceilometer et cetera come with Ubuntu Openstack Autopilot?

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot

## 1.

Since there is limited information(yes) about the current and updated status of ubuntu openstack autopilot on your website, i will like to find out if all services of openstack will come with ubuntu openstack autopilot. Services like Trove, Telemetry comes to mind and will like to know if those will come with ubuntu openstack autopilot

Pretty much interested in the Heat, Ceilometer and Trove in addition to the main components. I have seen Heat in videos on youtube but not the other two(ceilometer and trove).

## 2.

For the trial 10 nodes, can one have multiple availability zones? Like 2 availability zones with 5 servers in each?

Thanks